# React Typescript Failed to compile (TS error)

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, react-typescript

I cloned a project and when I'm trying to start it, I have Typescript errors.

```
Failed to compile.

./src/route/reset-password/reset-password-component.tsx
[tsl] ERROR in src/route/reset-password/reset-password-component.tsx(67,14)
      TS2314: Generic type 'SyntheticEvent<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).
```

How can I ignore these errors please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ts-ignore, by adding the comment on the line above where SyntheticEvent is being used.

So on line `66` in `src/route/reset-password/reset-password-component.tsx`

Example:

```
// @ts-ignore
const foo: SyntheticEvent = {
    ...
};
```

**Warning** I would use this with caution, as the error is most likely caused by something being incorrectly typed.

Comment: The problem is: I have 100+ errors and I don't want to set `// @ts-ignore` to all files. Can I make it global to the project ?

Comment: By doing this globally you would essentially be disabling TypeScript entirely and just using JS, so I am not aware of a way of doing this. You can add `// @ts-nocheck` to the top of a file to disable it for a whole file. However this will still be a long process if there is lots of files.